WPF Image Control Slow to Update with Large Images
I'm trying to update an Image control in WPF whenever new image data is fetched. I'm working with 1500x1500 16-bit RAW images (~5MB each), and I'm seeing an update time of around 22ms on average, which seems slow for my use case.
Currently, I'm loading images sequentially on a background task and updating the UI like this:
while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    if (imageCounter > 359)
        imageCounter = 0;

    //_memoryMappedViewAccessor.ReadArray(0, imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
    string path = $"{basePath}img{imageCounter++:D4}.raw";
    frame = ImageHelper.LoadImageRaw(path, Size, Size);

    await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        _writeableBitmap.Lock();
        _writeableBitmap.WritePixels(_rect, frame.Data, locStride, 0);
        _writeableBitmap.Unlock();
        ImageDisplay = _writeableBitmap;

        _frameCounter.Count();
    }, DispatcherPriority.Background, cancelToken);

}

Reading the data and writing to the WriteableBitmap takes about 2-3ms, which is expected. However, the entire update takes ~22ms, which suggests the internal redraw of the Image control is taking around 19ms for this kind of images.
I also used larger images of size 3000x3000. This resulted in a 4x slower speed (~80ms total, 8ms for loading the data), which at least seems plausible based on the relative size.
In addition I noticed the image display runs much faster when starting the app with a debugger attached.
Is this performance typical for the WPF Image control with large images? Or am I doing something wrong in my approach (especially because attaching a debugger seems to speed up the image drawing which is strange) that could be optimized for faster updates?

You do not need do Lock/Unlock for WritePixels. The assignment ImageDisplay = _writeableBitmap; needs to be done only once.

@Clemens Thanks for the note. However this does not improve the drawing. The assignment triggers OnPropertyChanged. My UI binds to ImageDisplay.

Try writing directly to the BackBuffer from the background thread. This would however need a Lock/Unlock sequence in the UI thread. See the Remarks for details.

For "The assignment triggers OnPropertyChanged" - that is pointless, because you are assigning a value that the property already has. Any change notification is ignored. The UI updates without it, by means of the WriteableBitmap internals.

@Clemens Thanks for poiting this out. You are correct that the OnPropertyChanged is useless here and is not even executed. I assign the WritableBitmap only once now and directly perform the operations on the ImageDisplay. Using unsafe code and directly writing to the BackBuffer did not change much. It only got a bit slower when a Debugger is attached compared to using WritePixels(). Without having a debugger attached there is no difference (still Release mode). I dont understand why this happens in the first place.

How exactly did you perform the timing measurements?

Each call to Count() calculates the time difference since the previous call and averages the last 20 entries every few milliseconds. I have also double checked the time measurements. The loaded images form an animation of a full rotation of an object. Based on this, you can manually calculate the average time it takes for one rotational step, and the results appear to be accurate with the counter im using. With attached debugger this animation is faster displayed visually + the counter shows average times of ~6ms which in my opinion indeed proves that the rendering runs faster.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Does that mean you are now measuring 6 instead of 22 ms? In case your problem is solved, consider writing an answer with the details of what exactly you have changed in your code.

@Clemens The 6ms are only measured when running the application with debugger attached from visual studio. Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I did not find a solution to update the 'Image' control faster. Instead im now using a OpenGL window thats embedded into a control, load the image as a texture and render it on a screen-filling quad. This works much better even with bigger image sizes.
